# Utility to continuously monitor an arbitrary command

Tags: linux, command-line, monitoring

I seem to recall there exists a small UNIX tool to repeatedly execute and display the output of another command at a given interval.

Kind of like "top" works by default but then for any other command.

Does anybody know such utility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is 'watch'